# Am I meant to create a models for an intermediate tables in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to check if a user has already liked a place so I need to check if there is already a record in the `Place_User` table. However, as of now I have not created a model for the intermediate table. I wouldn't even know how to name the model. Would Place_User make sense for a model name?

I have the following 3 tables:

```
Table: Users
Columns: id, username, password

Table: Places
Columns: id, place_id

Table: Place_User
Columns: id, user_id, place_id
```

I also have the 2 following models:

```
class User extends \Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticableTrait;

    public function places(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Place');
    }
}
```

And

```
class Place extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: When a pivot table is transformed to a model/entity I would recommend to give it is "function" as name. In your case, users *likes* places and places are *liked* by users.. So why not `Like` and `likes` table ? (as english not my native language, you may find even better synoyms) Later if your users may like various things; places, posts, comments... So you will have to check on polymorphism and maybe having `Likable` model instead of `Like`.

Comment: Yes but from the Laravel documentation I've gathered that an intermediate table should be named table1_table2 so I am just trying to follow the convention.

Comment: It depend of the purpose. I would recommend `tableA_tableB` when you use a **pivot** table that do only that, pivot. But when you transform you pivot to a model with an purpose, it's better to name it on is purpose.

Comment: But as far I understand your problem, you don't necessary needs to have a model

Comment: Seems like it, User::find(userId)->places->contains($placeId); did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry I got stuck with the end question _Would Place_User make sense for a model name?_ and got lost with my answer. Use a model only when you need it. But yes, it's a correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need an extra model for a many to many relationship. You can easily check if the user already liked the place like this:

```
User::find(1)->places->contains($placeId);

// or

User::find(1)->places()->where('place_id', $placeId)->exists();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should create models for pivot tables. **Dangling tables with no associated models are not really my choice.** Naming them can be a bit tough though, I would suggest `UserPlaces` for the sake of simplicity.

Why you should create models? So that you could define 2 relationships in the UserPlace model

1. User
2. Place

So in future, it's easy to navigate through relationships from the pivot table itself. Even though you won't be touching the pivot model/table directly most of the time.

Comment: You don't create models for pivot tables. Pivot table itself defines relationship among entities(one-to-many,many-to-many etc) and isn't an entity in itself.

Comment: @vivek_23 this is the case only for Many to Many, not for all of them.

Comment: @vivek_23 please read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). And tell me how would you setup as from the example there a Post to have many Comments? Without the `Comment` model? I mean you can avoid this for sure, but you will need to use the Query Builder always instead of the amazing Eloquent ORM.

Comment: @nakov `Comment` is not the pivot table there but an entity in itself. Ok, you may not need a pivot table(since you can just have an extra column there) and hence it doesn't need a model either.

Comment: @vivek_23 my point is not to argue here with you. The terminology that you use is a bit wrong I believe. There is no pivot table, but there are pivot columns that exist. The table is called Intermediate and it exists mostly between Many to Many, there is no case that I can think of that you will use it for One to Many relationship. 
Also at least in Laravel when you say Entity or Model, both refer to the same thing.

Comment: sorry to interrupt, I've highlighted the reason why I chose to write models for pivot table ;)

Comment: @nakov I apologize that my wording was incorrect although the theory was the same.

Comment: @Shobi The intermediary tables need not have models for itself. Can you explain more about `dangling` ?

Answer (score 1):

Recents version of Laravel 5.8 provide doc on the subject: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

But I don't think that pivot table should have a model.
Models represent your app Entities. Pivot tables are just there to store relations between entities.

If you just need to check existence of relation, there already are required tools :

```php
$hasPlace = User::find(1)->places()->where(/* ... */)->exists();
```

If you really need Model for your pivot tables, it is possible, but I believe that in most cases you need to rethink your DB shema.

Answer (score 0):

You can add method for pivot table in `User` model as, belongs to many should work for your case:

```
public function user_places()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Place', 'place_user', 
      'user_id', 'place_id');
}
```

I recommend using plural names of table to better readability to laravel.